# Adding an input value onto an existing value in a different activity

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm looking to create a running total on my MainActivity.java, this will be done through adding integers calculated in ActivityAdd.java then sending them across onClick save to a TextView in the MainActivity.java.

It's currently not opening the app due to the stack flow error stating invalid int "". Any advise on this?

AddActivity.Java

```
 OnClickListener button02OnClickListener =
            new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String theText = result.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("calorie", theText);
                startActivity(intent);

                }};
```

MainActivity.Java

```
   String calorie = getIntent().getStringExtra("calorie");
    TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Integer oldValue = Integer.parseInt(textView1.getText().toString());
    Integer newValue = Integer.parseInt(calorie);

    textView1.setText((oldValue + newValue));
```

StackFlow error

```
 02-24 09:42:39.873    2535-2535/com.example.student.neillapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.student.neillapp, PID: 2535
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.student.neillapp/com.example.student.neillapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
            at com.example.student.neillapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: What actually you want to do?I mean adding two numbers or Passing value from on activity to other or else?

Comment: First of all, you need to convert the `String` into `Integer`. Than you can fetch the value that is already there in `textView1` and add it to the value that you got from the intent. After that, set the total in `textView1` again.

Comment: @kishorJoshi  Adding two numberd, aiming to create a running total on the homepage (MainActivity).

Comment: What You want to do?I mean why are you adding two numbers.If you can explain your objective then we can understand what actually you want to do.

Comment: Use `Integer.parseInt(calorie)` to get the value from intent. `Integer.parseInt(textView1.getText().toString())` to get the value from textView. Then add these value and get the String using `theSum + ""`

Comment: @kishorJoshi I want to take my calories from one activity, and present them on my main activity. I then want any additional calories to be added onto any existing calories on the main activity... My application is a food application that counts the users daily calories.

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak Like this?                                                       String calorie = getIntent().getStringExtra("calorie");
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        int cal =  Integer.parseInt(calorie);
        int excal = Integer.parseInt(textView1.getText().toString());
       total = cal + excal;
       textView1.setText(total);

Comment: You can store that value in SQLiteDatabase and you again can get that value from the database and add new value from AddActivity and show on...

Comment: @Tom you are right. That is what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error occurs due to Empty String `""` in `textView1`.

You are not checking if the String is Blank or not.

So, I added extra 2 lines.

```
String calorie = getIntent().getStringExtra("calorie");
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

String strOldValue = textView1.getText().toString();
//Integer oldValue = StringUtils.isNotBlank(myString) ? Integer.parseInt(myString) : 0;

//UPDATE: Replace above with
//Integer oldValue = (myString != null && !myString.isEmpty()) ? Integer.parseInt(myString) : 0;

//UPDATE:
Integer oldValue = 0;
try {
    oldValue = Integer.parseInt(myString);
} catch(Exception e) {
    //oldValue = 0;
}

Integer newValue = Integer.parseInt(calorie);

textView1.setText((oldValue + newValue));
```

I think this might help you.

Comment: How do i use StringUtils and myString ... getting 'cannot resolve symbol' for both of them. Thanks

Comment: Replace `StringUtils.isNotBlank(myString)` with `myString != null && !myString.isEmpty()`. I have changed the answer.

Comment: The application doesn't open on emulator, with "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"" .. hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood , what you are looking for is starting an activity for result...

So to do that in your main activity you have to start the ActivityAdd for result like so..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityAdd.class);

startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Also in the main activity then you override method onActivityResult like so :

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
        //UPDATE TEXTVIEWS HERE
        //DATA IS THE INTENT
    }
  }
```

Now in our add activity we must return result once we have it..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("calorie", theText);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

finish();
```

Comment: Yes so, ActivityAdd.class is where i'm calculating a calorie value for a food item... ActivityMain.class is where i'm looking to add up all food items added from ActivityAdd, resulting in an integer result Textview for a users total calories consumed that day on my Homepage (ActivityMain)

Comment: if you follow my steps you should do exactly that

Comment: starnge..can you post your onCreate method than?

Answer (score 0):

In you `MainActivity.java`

```
String calorie = getIntent().getStringExtra("calorie");
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
Integer oldValue = Integer.parseInt(textView1.getText().toString());
Integer newValue = Integer.parseInt(calorie);

//setText() needs a String to set so you can do anyone of the following

textView1.setText(""+(oldValue + newValue));
or

Integer total = oldValue + newValue;
textView1.setText(total.toString());
```

Comment: This gives me an error on my onclick in ActivityAdd... java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: Where did you add this code? It should be in your `ActivityMain.java`

Comment: Yes, replaced my 3 lines with your 5 lines.. that is all. application crashes

Comment: Can you post the whole stake trace. Also your file name is `ActivityMain.java` and you are creating an intent of `MainActivity.class` in `ActivityAdd.java`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Can you make sure that the `id` of the textBox is `textBox4` only?

Comment: Ops a section was uncommented, i've fixed that but now i've got java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" ... when opening the app

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the edited code and the stack trace with the current exception?

Comment: Cant it use the same calorie string? could you elaborate?

Comment: For addition, you need integers. If you do `+` on strings, it will concatenate those strings. e.g. `a + b = ab`. So you will need at least one `Integer` variable to perform the addition and to store the result. If you want to decrease the number of variables, it can be worked around.